# Pagination with AJAX in combination with searchbox

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a script (from W3schools) that I can use to search the db while typing text into it. This works fine.

Second I have a script that is used for paginating the ajaxResult. This also works fine.

But when I combine these scripts the pagination stops working.

Or is there any other way to combine the search with pagination?

Here is my code:

```
<body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container">  
                <h3 align="center">Make Pagination using Jquery, PHP, Ajax and MySQL</h3><br />  
                <input type="text" onkeyup="showCustomer(this.value)"><br>
                <div class="table-responsive" id="txtHint">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="pagination_data">  
                </div>  
           </div>  

</body>

<script>
//script to search the db while typing 

function showCustomer(str) {

var xhttp;
  //var params = page;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "test.php?q="+str, true);
  xhttp.send();


}

</script> 

 <script> 
//script to paginate
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      load_data();  
      function load_data(page)  
      {  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"test.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{page:page},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $('#pagination_data').html(data);  
                }  
           })  
      }  
      $(document).on('click', '.pagination_link', function(){  
           var page = $(this).attr("id");  
           load_data(page);  
      });  
 });  

 </script>
```

Comment: I dont understand why you would do it at all, as the user types a search should reduce the results, how are they going to look though pages as they try to type into a text field.  just saying.

Comment: Beacause the filtered data is still large and i don't want to display all filtereddata at once.

Comment: Anyone who can help me with this issue..?